# Woo Commerc API - GET Products returning "1"

Tags: json, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am calling Woo commerce's API through a REST Client however the API is responding with 200 OK however the body (Should be JSON) is returning "1".

the method i am calling is

Method: GET

URL: https://site/wc-api/v3/products?consumer_key=consumerkey&consumer_secret=consumersecret

Header: Accept: application/json;

The response;

response header:

- Status Code: 200 OK
- Connection: keep-alive
- Content-Encoding: gzip
- Content-Type: text/html
- Date: Wed, 16 Dec 2015 02:50:14 GMT
- Server: nginx/1.6.1
- Transfer-Encoding: chunked
- X-CF-Powered-By: WP 1.3.14
- X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.32

response body: 1

- WC Version: 2.4.12
- WP Version: 4.3.1

I am not sure what the issue is, i have tried HTTPS using oAuth and HTTP using base Auth.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i have found a solution...

The dev store is on a sub-domain (dev.site.com). The webserver was configured incorrectly and redirecting to the production site.

The production site was running an earlier version of WooCommerce - one that didn't have version 3 of the API (The dev site had the latest version of WooCommerce).